# how to get value from a coroutine

Tags: unity-game-engine

I used WWW for loading a texture of an Image

```
pictureObj myPicture = new pictureObj();
myPicture.url = result;
myPicture.Id = cnt;
WWW imgLoad = new WWW(result);
myPicture.texture = imgLoad.texture;
```

I get warning that WWW is obsolete. So I started using UnityWebRequestTexture.GetTexture 
as the code samples I looked into that I need to start a coroutine and then load the texture in another method.

```
IEnumerator GetTexture(string filePath)
{
    using (UnityWebRequest req = UnityWebRequestTexture.GetTexture(filePath))
    {
        yield return req.SendWebRequest();
        if (req.isNetworkError)
        {
            Debug.Log(req.error);
        }
        else
        {
            myPicture.texture = DownloadHandlerTexture.GetContent(req); 
        }
    }
}
```

in my code I save the texture in myPicture but since the coroutine method is outside the brackets where I initialize my object. I also add the pictureObj to a list so its dynamic and cant use myPicture as gloabal variable.

is it possible to use coroutine method with the same place I call it or return texture value from coroutine. something like

```
pictureObj myPicture = new pictureObj();
myPicture.url = result;
myPicture.Id = cnt;
myPicture.texture = [texture from UnityWebRequest coroutine]
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know unity coroutine can't do that , But you can use callback like this

```
pictureObj myPicture = new pictureObj();
myPicture.url = result;
myPicture.Id = cnt;
StartCoroutine(GetTexture("xxx", (Texture t ) =>  { myPicture.texture = t; })); 

IEnumerator GetTexture(string filePath , System.Action<Texture> callback)
{
    using (UnityWebRequest req = UnityWebRequestTexture.GetTexture(filePath))
    {
        yield return req.SendWebRequest();
        if (req.isNetworkError)
        {
            Debug.Log(req.error);
        }
        else
        {
            callback(DownloadHandlerTexture.GetContent(req));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why dont use a static variable? You put the definition in anyscript loaded

```
public static class MyTexture
{
    public static Texture texture; //dont know the type of texture, so replace
}
```

then in coroutine you do:

```
          MyTexture.texture = DownloadHandlerTexture.GetContent(req);
```

then in script, you do

```
          myPicture.texture = MyTexture.texture;
```

Comment: I can but I need that texture right after I call it
I give up and call the web request as in examples and create and fill my myPicture obj in the IEnumarator method

Comment: sorry but i am lost could you elaborate the sequence of scripts, when you launch coroutine..